# Problems with binary long handling

Tags: c++

I made a binary decimal conversion menu which always take 0 for binary numbers

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int dec,ch,i;
    long bin,temp;
    do
    {
        dec=bin=i=ch=0;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tMENU\n1. Deciml to Binary number\n2. Binary to Decimal number\n3. Exit\n";
        cout<<"Enter your choice(1/2/3)> ";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: cout<<"Enter a decimal number: ";cin>>dec;
                temp=dec;
                while(dec)
                {
                    bin+=(dec%2)*pow(10,i);
                    dec/=2;
                    i++;
                }
                cout<<temp<<" in decimal = "<<bin<<" in binary"<<endl;break;
            case 2: cout<<"Enter a binary number: ";cin>>bin;
                temp=bin;
                while(bin)
                {
                    dec+=(bin%10)*pow(2,i);
                    bin/=10;
                    i++;
                }
                cout<<temp<<" in binary = "<<dec<<" in decimal"<<endl;break;
            case 3: break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid choice";
        }
    }while(ch!=3);
}
```

When I select choice `1` and enter `23`, it gives `0` and when I enter `11001` in choice `2` it gives `0` and tells that I entered `0`.

**Output:**

```cpp
                MENU
1. Deciml to Binary number
2. Binary to Decimal number
3. Exit
Enter your choice(1/2/3)> 1
Enter a decimal number: 23
23 in decimal = 0 in binary


                MENU
1. Deciml to Binary number
2. Binary to Decimal number
3. Exit
Enter your choice(1/2/3)> 2
Enter a binary number: 11001
0 in binary = 0 in decimal


                MENU
1. Deciml to Binary number
2. Binary to Decimal number
3. Exit
Enter your choice(1/2/3)> 3

--------------------------------
Process exited after 7.103 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: do not put everything in `main`. Please Learn to split code into smaller functions each responsible for small part of problem. It will be easier to write and read code, also it will be easier to ask question since the you can provide [mcve] without special effort.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] since it [seams to work](https://godbolt.org/z/5ss48nqo7) - even though there are problems with code.

Comment: You're not converting between decimal and binary representations, you're converting one number (which is input in the decimal notation) to a different number (which is output in the decimal notation).

Comment: That is, if your program worked, you would be "converting" eleven to either three or one thousand and eleven, depending on the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is that many newbies have wrong mindset when trying to solve this problem.

They assume the have to recalculate directly from decimal to binary. They amuse that `int` type some some kind of magic aware of desired base.
In this insane approach they are trying to calculate a value, which printed in decimal representation could be read as desired binary value.
This is wrong and bug prone!!!

Real conversion which should happen should be done in two steps:

- reading text representing a value in decimal format, then convert it to internal machine representation of that value (it not relay important that CPU uses binary, important thing is that you have a some value in CPU). This is covered by library: `std::cin >> intVariable;`.
- then this value should be converted to text representing value in binary format. Standard library do not have such functionality (not really true, but I will not confuse you how). So task is calculate each digit and then print it or store it in text representation.

So to fix your code by trying write this function:

```cpp
void printAsBinary(std::ostream& out, int x)
{
   for ( .... ) {
       ....
       out << ( someCondition ? '1' : '0');
   }
}
```

Comment: Cool I have a vote down, but I wish I see a comment explaining why answer is wrong so I could improve it or deleted it or learn something new.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted but I need to use long

Comment: so replace `int` with  `long`. My point is do conversion `integer type` -> `string with text representation of number in base X` not the thing you are doing.

Comment: I need to use int and long according to my syllabus